# I can´t install Anaconda on Linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, anaconda, failed-installation

When I try to install Anaconda on Linux, I get to this point:

```
Anaconda3 will now be installed into this location:
/home/jorge/anaconda3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/home/jorge/anaconda3] >>> 
PREFIX=/home/jorge/anaconda3
Unpacking payload ...
```

Then I receive the following error message:

```
concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback:                                        
'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 367, in _queue_management_worker
  File "multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'
'''

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "entry_point.py", line 69, in <module>
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 483, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 598, in result_iterator
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 435, in result
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
[1770] Failed to execute script entry_point
```

What can I do? I was following all the instructions step by step

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you verify the integrity of the installer's data? because it is a common error when downloading this corrupted or incomplete
since it is the previous step you have to do to make sure that the file is ok before executing the script.
This post helped me a lot for the first time I installed it.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart

Comment: That tutorial is for an older Anaconda version. I checked the hash after download, and it is okay. I still have the above error with `Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh` on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Okay, in my case, it was because the drive was low on space. There were only around 2.5 GB available, and the install went well after freeing more space.

Comment: @meferne Same here in my case, it was because the drive was low on space. installed after freeing up space

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar problem where available storage (disk space) was only 1.2 GB. Please make sure that you have enough free storage space to install it. To check available space, type

`df -h /home/`

Comment: "memory" or disk space?

Comment: Yes, it's disk space. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: This answer is correct. I encountered the same issue. I just needed to cleanup the space & it works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the root cause was the encrypted home folder (on Linux Mint 21.2). The encryption sets limits to the maximum allowed filename length which causes the error (though the error message is not directly helpful...). Installing in an unencrypted folder worked without issues.

Comment: This was my problem as well! Thank you so much for figuring this out!

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error on Linux Mint but I was able to install Anaconda in `/root/` using `sudo`:

```bash
sudo bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-*.sh
```

But when I tried to copy it to my encrypted `$HOME` directory I had the same problem that [kricki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12311771/kricki) had ('ERROR: File name too long').

So you should symlink to `/root/anaconda3` from `/opt/anaconda3` and make both `anaconda3` dirs read/write/execute/search-able by normal users:

```bash
sudo chmod -R ugoa+Xrw /opt/anaconda3
sudo chmod 755 /root/
sudo chmod 755 /root/anaconda3
sudo echo "Make sure **$USER** is you and not **root** before running chown"
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /root/anaconda3
chmod -R ugoa+Xrw /root/anaconda3
sudo ln -s /root/anaconda3 /opt/anaconda3
sudo chmod 755 /opt/anaconda3
sudo chown $USER:$USER /opt/anaconda3
chmod ugoa+Xrw /opt/anaconda3
```

Now you should be able to add `conda` to your $PATH in `.bashrc` by running `conda init`:

```bash
/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda init
```

Now when you close your terminal and relaunch it, you should see `(base)` at the beginning of your prompt and `conda` should work normally:

```bash
(base) $ conda --version
conda 23.7.2
```